# Is it possible to use TextFieldParser with Byte?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, csv

Is it possible to use TextFieldParser on `Byte`?  I am uploading a file via a Web Service using `Byte` and I am having some trouble figuring out if I can access this CSV directly or if I need to first write it to disk.  Writing it to disk would be easy, but I am not convinced I need to do so.

[TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.textfieldparser.aspx) accepts `System.IO.Stream`, `System.String` (path to file), or `System.IO.TextReader` but I cannot figure out if I can get the Byte into one of those easily.

This is what I am looking at and what I would like to do (this code doesn't work)

```
Public Function Import(ValidationKey As String, FileBytes() As Byte) As String

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(FileBytes)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        'other code here
    End Using

    'other code here

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the `byte` array into a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) - `TextFieldParser` will accept it.

```
Using MemStream As New MemoryStream(FileBytes)
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(MemStream)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        'other code here
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, +1 for you!